# How to include a config file in the "META-INF/services" folder of a JAR using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse, which is built using Maven. I'm using some recycled code from an older project, and one of these classes looks for a file in the `META-INF/services` folder of the JAR with a particular name, then parses the text of this file. In this particular example, it looks for a file with the name of a Java interface, then grabs the class name of the implementation from inside the file.

So basically what I'm trying to do is **include a file in the "META-INF/services" folder of the JAR with a file name (X), and one line of text (Y)**. I'm guessing this should be done using Maven, maybe by specifying an attribute in the POM file, but my research hasn't turned up anything. I know you're not supposed to hard-code or manually type out any META files, so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: After 8 years, getting a Maven project to recognize the META-INF/services folder is still insanely hard. If even possible.

Comment: Note that after Java 8, this whole mehtod is outdated and all the service provider stuff has moved to the module-info.java file.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

[Create a new source folder](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-source-folder.htm) with the location `src/main/resources`, then create your `META-INF/services` folder in there and drop in your fully-qualified class name (FQCN) file. This should copy them into the jar file automatically. So for implementations of an interface with a FQCN of `com.acme.MyInterface`, you'll have:

```
Project
| src
| | main
|   | java
|     | [your source code]
|   | resources
|     | META-INF
|       | services
|         | com.acme.MyInterface
```

Note that `com.acme.MyInterface` is the name of the file, not a directory structure like a Java package. The name of the file is the FQCN of the interface that you're implementing, and in it, you'll have the FQCN of each implementation on its own line, e.g.:

```
com.example.MyInterfaceImpl
com.example.AnotherMyInterfaceImpl
```

It's worth noting that this applies to Gradle projects with the default source sets as well.

Once you do this, you can load all the implementations of the interface using `ServiceLoader`:

```
ServiceLoader<MyInterface> loader = ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface.class);
for (MyInterface service : loader) {
    // Prints com.example.MyInterfaceImpl and com.example.AnotherMyInterfaceImpl
    System.out.println(service.class.getName());
}
```

Some things to note:

- All the implementations must have a no-args constructor
- Applications that use modules or custom classloaders may have to use the overloads of `ServiceLoader.load`

If these conditions won't work for you, then you may want to switch to another system, e.g. a CDI-style framework like Spring, EJB, etc.

Comment: What to put in services folder?

Comment: @OzanKurt Please have a look at the Javadoc of the ServiceLoader class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: @OzanKurt [Here's the related Java trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#register-service-providers). In short, the file's name inside META-INF/services will be something like META-INF/services/com.acme.MyInterface and it will contain each FQCN of the implementations in your application, each on a new line, e.g. `com.example.MyInterfaceImpl`

Comment: META-INF/services/com.acme.MyInterface or META-INF/services/com/acme/MyInterface?

Comment: @Gerry -- the first one. I'll update my answer to reflect this better.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with spring boot?
With `spring-boot-maven-plugin` `repackage` goal the `src/main/resources/META-INF` is not copied to root `META-INF`, but instead is copied as `BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF` which seems to mean the service is not auto detected.

Comment: @Sodved – if you're using Spring Boot, is there a solution for you that uses Spring Boot autowiring/autoconfig instead of Java SPI? I've found similar questions to yours, but I haven't been able to find a concrete solution.

Comment: Sorry @Brian, no luck. Only thing that works is to build the application jar with maven assembly or shade plugins. This potentially has other issues, and is non-standard in our organisation. But looking like our only option that I can see

Answer (score 28):

By default Maven looks for resources at:

```
src/main/resources
```

So put it at

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services
```

Comment: What to put in services folder?

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, if your project does not use a standard directory structure (or your simply wish to have alternate resource directories), you can specify [resource directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) manually the POM file.

For example, if your `META-INF/services` is located in a folder called `resources` which lies in the root of your project directory, could specify it as follows:

```
<project>
...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

You can use this to specify several directories by adding multiple `<resource>` elements.

Comment: What to put in services folder?

Comment: @OzanKurt I'm not sure of everything that goes in there, but one example of a file that lives in META-INF/services normally is a custom CharsetProvider.

Comment: I got this, needed to add annotations. Thanks