# java.util.ServiceLoader.load() function is useless and only returns empty result

Tags: java, scala, reflection, serviceloader

I'm trying to use Java ServiceLoader in Scala 2.10 to find all my test classes by reflection:

```
  val services = ServiceLoader.load(classOf[MyClass])
  for (service <- services.asScala) {
    test(service.getClass.getCanonicalName) {
      println(service)
      ... test code
    }
  }
```

I'm very sure 'MyClass' has several subclasses which contains test cases, as I can use 'classOf[]' function to find them in the same code snippet

However, my test always ends with

```
Empty test suite.
```

Is the ServiceLoader not working in Scala? How to fix or circumvent this problem?

Comment: You didn't even show enough code to see where that "Empty test suite." message comes from. What happens if you dump `services` right at the beginning? Have you tried interactive debugging? Where's your `META-INF/services/` file?

Comment: you are right the META-INF/services/ is missing, looks like its not a fully automatic class detector. The Empty test suite message is thrown by scala test in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to set the META-INF/services/ file, after adding the binary name of the service class everything goes normal!

Comment: Explain what to do with services folder

Comment: @OzanKurt Probably write `com.example.impl.MyInterfaceImpl` in the file `META-INF/services/com.example.MyInterface` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531625/how-to-include-a-config-file-in-the-meta-inf-services-folder-of-a-jar-using-ma