# Drools fat jar nullpointer KieServices

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, drools, sbt-assembly

I'm generating a fat jar of my project using sbt assembly.
Then, when trying to run my jar file, i get a nullpointer on this line:

```
val kieServices: KieServices = KieServices.Factory.get
val kieContainer: KieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer
```

I've already tried adding a `kie.conf`, but this does not help. I am not using maven or a pom file etc. And am using scala sbt.

Running drools' latest version.

build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "untitled",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.drools" % "drools-core" % "8.31.1.Final",
      "org.drools" % "drools-compiler" % "8.31.1.Final",
      "org.drools" % "drools-decisiontables" % "8.31.1.Final",
      "org.drools" % "drools-mvel" % "8.31.1.Final",
      "org.drools" % "drools-model-compiler" % "8.31.1.Final",
      "org.kie" % "kie-api" % "8.31.1.Final"
    ),
    resolvers in Global ++= Seq(
      "Sbt plugins" at "https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases",
    ),
    Compile / packageBin / mainClass := Some("src.Main"),
    Compile / run / mainClass := Some("src.Main")
  )
  .settings(
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "myJar.jar",
    assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    },
  )
```

project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

src/main/scala/src/Main.scala (sorry not sorry):

```
package src

import org.kie.api.KieServices
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer

object Main extends App {
  val kieServices: KieServices = KieServices.Factory.get
  val kieContainer: KieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"Then, when trying to run my jar file, i get a nullpointer on this line"* This not a line, this is two lines. Did you try to debug what exactly is null?

Comment: KieServices is null, kieContainer causes the error because of a call to the null object @DmytroMitin

Comment: Would you provide MCVE? For example your `build.sbt`

Comment: I have added a MCVE @DmytroMitin

Comment: Managed to reproduce NPE (had to use Java 11+ to avoid `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/kie/api/runtime/KieContainer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`).

Comment: Hm that is a different error though

Comment: That was because while working with Scala I normally use Java 8. With Java 11+ (actually, 17) I managed to reproduce NPE. Probably you use Java 11+.

Comment: Correct.
With Java 11, you get the following:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Main$.main(Main.scala:5)`

Which is the `getKieClasspathContainer` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging shows that

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

ServiceLoader.load(classOf[KieServices], classOf[KieServices].getClassLoader)
 .asScala.size
```

is 1 when I do `sbt run` but 0 when I do `java -jar myJar.jar`.

In the former case `KieServices.Factory.get` returns `org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl@...some...hashcode...` but in the latter case it returns `null`.

Try to add a file `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.kie.api.KieServices` with content

```
org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl
```

One more issue is that, on contrary to `sbt package`, `sbt assembly` is missing this file from the assembly jar. So try to unpack `myJar.jar`, put manually this file as `myJar.jar/META-INF/services/org.kie.api.KieServices` and zip the jar back (`myJar.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` should exist but `myJar.jar/META-INF/services` is probably missing: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/11)

[java.util.ServiceLoader.load() function is useless and only returns empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381539/java-util-serviceloader-load-function-is-useless-and-only-returns-empty-result)

[How to include a config file in the "META-INF/services" folder of a JAR using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531625/how-to-include-a-config-file-in-the-meta-inf-services-folder-of-a-jar-using-ma)

---

It's missing from assembly jar because of

```
assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
```

in your `build.sbt`. So modify the strategy:

```
assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.kie.api.KieServices") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

and service file will be included into assembly jar.

---

Actually, the service file already exists in the dependency: `~/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/drools/drools-compiler/8.31.1.Final/drools-compiler-8.31.1.Final.jar:META-INF/services/org.kie.api.KieServices`

So you shouldn't add it manually, just do `case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.kie.api.KieServices") => MergeStrategy.concat`.

There are different service files in `drools-compiler-8.31.1.Final.jar:META-INF/services/` so be careful with `case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard`, it's possible you'll have more problems later if you ignore service files.

---

Try

```
assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "services", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.concat
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Hm, whilst this does solve the nullpointer, a new error has appeared:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.drools.wiring.api.ComponentsFactory.createProjectClassLoader(ComponentsFactory.java:34) at org.drools.wiring.api.classloader.ProjectClassLoader.createProjectClassLoader(ProjectClassLoader.java:99) at org.drools.wiring.api.classloader.ProjectClassLoader.createProjectClassLoader(ProjectClassLoader.java:92) at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:96)
`

Comment: @GSerum_ Why are you ignoring the files from `META-INF`?

Comment: I don't know, that's just the code that was already there (company code), but your new case worked, thanks!

Comment: Certainly, thank you @dmytromitin
I do have a final question, unrelated probably. It now no longer finds the KieSession name, probably due to the ksession.xml not being copied over correctly? I tried to add it similarly using `case PathList("META-INF", "kmodule.xml") => MergeStrategy.concat`, but that does not work...
Line is `val kieSession: KieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("DroolDummyKS")`.
It works when running normally (not via jar)

Comment: @GSerum_ It's hard to guess without reproduction. You should start a new question providing the content of `kmodule.xml`, where you put it, current `build.sbt`, what error you have (*"that does not work"* is a bad description). Is it possible that you have several `kmodule.xml`? Would `concat` make sense then? You can check with `singleOrError`.

Comment: @GSerum_ Please start a new question with a proper description.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144484/sbt-assembly-deduplication-found-error