# META-INF/spring.factories file missing from Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am fairly new to Spring and Spring Boot, and was asked to work on a legacy Spring Boot project. I am supposed to include in the project some [FailureAnalyzer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/FailureAnalyzer.html)s provided by Spring Boot. According to tutorials I came across (like [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failure-analyzer)), all that needs to be done is registering the several FailureAnalyzer classes in the META-INF/spring.factories file.

But when I build the project (using Maven), I don't see a spring.factories file inside the target/META-INF directory. I tried adding one myself but it doesn't seem to be read by the project. What am I missing? What should I be doing to register these FailureAnalyzers?

In case you need it, the spring.factories file looks like this:

```
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.AbstractInjectionFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanCurrentlyInCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BindFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ConnectorStartFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.PortInUseFailureAnalyzer,\
  org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ValidationExceptionFailureAnalyzer
```

Comment: Those are registered by default why would you need to register them manually?! You only need to register your own custom analyzers NOT the default ones.

Comment: Is META-INF folder under resources? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531625/how-to-include-a-config-file-in-the-meta-inf-services-folder-of-a-jar-using-ma

Comment: There is no need to do that, Spring Boot itself does provide them already. It would help if you'd describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll i created spring boot gradle project using spring initializer. But i don't see `spring.factories` anywhere in my project. Just wondering where it is located

Comment: You don't need a `spring.factories` there. Please do not comment on unrelated issue and create your own with more details

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mistaken the location of spring.factories file. This file will not be present in the project resources folder. Go to Maven dependencies and look into each Jar META-INF file and you will find spring.factories file in most of the jars.

[image]